# Разница IE под Mac и Windows

Tags: windows, вёрстка, virtualbox

Сказали что `IE` под `MacOS` и под `Windows` совершенно разные, и тестировать надо с вируталки, хотя уже через `WineBottle` и `CrossOver` пробовал вроде нормально?
Верно ли утверждение и надо ставить виртуалку?

Comment: Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но последняя версия IE под Mac вышла в 2003 году. оно вам точно надо?

Comment: У меня тоже в голове витает схожий вопрос. Есть ли разница в работе браузеров в разных ОС?

Comment: >Есть ли разница в работе браузеров в разных ОС?

в идеале ее, наверное, быть но должно, но ключевое слово здесь "в идеале". Я бы не стал уповать на полную идентичность. Ну а по сабжу - тут по определению понятно, что сравнивая нынешний IE под Windows и его древнющую реализацию под Mac явно не стоит ждать их идентичности

Comment: C ИЕ то понятно, а как быть, например, с хромом. Есть ли такая разница или её нет?

Comment: @DreamChild у меня сейчас через CrossOver стоит 8-ка, и похожими методами думаю поставить 9-10, но вопрос озадачил.

@Genson если Chrome  то тогда уже и Firefox ?